# Excel to json file from Excel VBA

Tags: html, json, excel, vba

I want to have a button in an excel document (using VBA) which, takes in the data on the sheet and outputs a file (.json). Which I can then use later on within a web page.

I my excel data looks like this:

[image: Image of excel table]

Note  I would like to have more than one instance of data.
I want it to generate a json file in the format of:

```html
{
 "Excel_test": [
  {
   "name" : "tesintg1",
   "age" : 15
  },
  {
   "name" : "testng2",
   "age" : 1
  },
  {
   "name" : "testing3",
   "age" : 435
  }
 ]
}
Thanks
```

Comment: Why don't you do this with help of a proper programming language?

Comment: What do you mean a proper programming language?

Comment: Build an app in Python, C#, Java or anything else to read the Excel file and ouput JSON, much more straightforward than programming a macro in VBA.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look into it, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open-source [VBA-JSON project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) helps with this.

Once you have [installed it](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON#installation) in your workbook's VBA project, you can do something like this:

```vb
Sub convertJson()

    Dim c As Collection
    Dim d As Dictionary 'Add reference to scripting runtime
    Dim v As Dictionary
    Dim json As String

    Set c = New Collection
    Set d = New Dictionary


    d.Add "ExcelTest", c
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A4") 'Adapt as you need
        Set v = New Dictionary
        v.Add "name", cell.Value
        v.Add "age", cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        c.Add v
    Next
    
    json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(d)

    Debug.Print json
    
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```json
{"ExcelTest":[{"name":"test1","age":15},{"name":"test2","age":1},{"name":"test3","age":435}]}
```

Comment: When I run this example I get an error on Dim d As Dictionary. Where you put add reference to scripting run time what do you mean?

Comment: Go to the VBA editor > Tools > References and select the library Microsoft Scripting Runtime